# In Magento 2, what determines the path used for requirejs?

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I have two installations of the same code looking at the same database, and when I deploy the static code I get different files created by each:

1) creates `pub/static/_requirejs/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/requirejs-config.js`

2) creates `pub/static/_requirejs/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/secure/requirejs-config.js`

I'm guessing this is to do with the secure URLs, but they have identical `app/etc/env.php` files. What determines which is created?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be determined by environment variables. By running static deployment as follows, I get the secure version:

```
https=on php ./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```